# How to have two objects travelling different distance at the same speed?

Tags: .net, silverlight, storyboard

Using Silverlight and a Storyboard, how to have two objects travelling different distance at the same speed? Right now, to animate my controls I am using the code below. However, if one control has to travel 100 pixels and the other one 1000 pixels, the animation doesn't run at the same speed. The one with a 100 pixels travelling distance is much slower. This is due to the duration of the animation, but I have to set it if I want the animation to run.

Is there another way to do this and make sure that whatever the distance a control has to travel, the speed of the movement is going to be the same?

```
var easefall = new QuadraticEase();
easefall.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn;

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.To = // 10, 50, 100...
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.50);
animation.EasingFunction = easefall;
```

Comment: I assume you want the item with a shorter distance to travel to complete its animation earlier? If not, I think we have to invoke relativity.

Comment: If you want constant speed, you need to increase the duration directly proportional to the distance.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I understand that, but I would expect something in Silverlight to do that for me. I don't want the time to be a constant, I want te speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CodeInChaos mentioned, you may need to add a variable or two in order to make your travel rate constant, but this should work regardless of the distance to travel.

```
double rate = 0.05; //speed per unit of one change
double duration = distance * rate; //i'll assume your distance is an input from somewhere

var easefall = new QuadraticEase();
easefall.EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn;

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
animation.To = // 10, 50, 100...
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
animation.EasingFunction = easefall;
```